# Replace string that includes parenthesis in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to replace a string that includes a **parenthesis** in my C# email script with a given variable. A snippet of my code inside a function goes like this:

```
MailDefinition md = new MailDefinition();

md.From = "testmail@test.com";    
string addressee = salutation;

ListDictionary replacements = new ListDictionary();
replacements.Add("\n", "<br />");
replacements.Add("(Name of Employee)", addressee)       
string body = EmployeeQuery.getEmailMessageByCategory(category, subcategory);
MailMessage msg = md.CreateMailMessage("admin@test.com", replacements, body, new System.Web.UI.Control());
```

the main issue is this part of the code:

```
replacements.Add("(Name of Employee)", addressee)
```

the "Name of Employee" gets replaced by the value of addressee variable. However, it doesn't replace the parenthesis.

How can I replace the **parenthesis** as well so that only the value of addressee is added? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put "\\(" and "\\)".
 @denims answer is probably partly correct, but c# itself interprets the \ in the string. You probably need the \ to be interpreted by the method you're calling.

That said the method documentation doesn't indicate why this is happening in the first place.

Comment: thanks. Yeah it did it. Actually @AndrewBacker got it first correctly on his comment on Denim's answer

Answer (score 1):

Use This :

```
replacements.Add("\\(Name of Employee\\)", addressee)

// \ acts as escape charecter, supressing the special meaning of next charecter
// (XYZ) matches XYZ  as a group
// \\(XYZ\\) matches (XYZ)
```

Comment: sorry but it produced an error: Error 1 Unrecognized escape sequence

Comment: use a verbatim string.  the "\" is also an escape character in C#.  You can use `@"\( ...."` or escape manually like `"\\(name ...\\)"`

Comment: Sorry for the mistake. Was unaware of this fact in C#.

Comment: its ok @Denim. Your answer was much appreciated